# changing the surface graph colors in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1EKt.png)

In this graph I want to change the surface colors. I want to represent the area in red by blue and the area in blue by red. So in the scale values closer to 1, would be represented by blue color and values closer to 0 by red color. How can I make this adjustment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually modify the colormap to make the adjustment. Let's take an example using the `jet` [colormap](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html).

Here's the original figure:

```
figure;
surf(peaks);
```

[image: original with jet]

Now we take a jet colormap with 128 values, flip it and assign it to the axes:

```
cmap = jet(128); %// get colormap you want
cmap = flipud(cmap); %// flip colormap
colormap(cmap); %//assign colormap
```

Which has the effect desired, blue colour is shown for large values and red for small:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you please tell me what `jet(128) ` means? How to select what value to be chosen for 128?

Comment: @clarkson Did you read the documentation at the link in the first line of this answer?